# Using JQuery for refreshing page but not getting desire results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using Jquery for refreshing page i it is refreshing but when i select one option from my category it is refreshing and then my selected category be disappear but i want when i select any one option the page will be refresh but my selected option will also be the same which i selected hope you guys will understand my problem.

```
$(function() { $('select[name="cat"]').change(function() { location.href = 'insert_book.php?cat=' + $(this).find('option:selected').val(); }); });
    <select id="rf" name="cat">
                    <option value='null'>Select your Desire</option>
                    <?php
                    include('includes/db.php');
                    $c_query="select * from categories";
                    $c_run=(mysql_query($c_query));
                    while($c_row=mysql_fetch_array($c_run)){
                        $c_id=$c_row['p_id'];
                        $c_title=$c_row['p_title'];
                        echo "<option value='$c_id'>$c_title</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

Comment: To clarify: You want the user to select an option, refresh the page, and have that option selected on page load?

Comment: You're using `mysql_*` functions for database access -- you should be aware that the library is deprecated. That means it is no longer maintained, and will be removed in a future version. You should use newer database access methods, like PDO, in any new code you write. Otherwise, what you're spending time on today will have to be revisited later when it completely stops working. Check out [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your refresh code to this:

```
$(function() {
    $('select[name="cat"]').change(function(ev) { 
        location.href = 'insert_book.php?cat=' + $(ev.currentTarget).val(); 
    }); 
});
```

Also move this JS code after the HTML code for the `select` element or wrap it with `$(document).ready()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name="cat"]').change(function(ev) { 
        location.href = 'insert_book.php?cat=' + $(ev.currentTarget).val(); 
    }); 
});
```

Now in the loop code:

```
$selectedCategory = array_key_exists('cat', $_GET) ? $_GET['cat'] : 0;
while($c_row=mysql_fetch_array($c_run)){
    $c_id=$c_row['p_id'];
    $c_title=$c_row['p_title'];
    echo "<option value='$c_id'".($selectedCategory == $c_id ? " selected='selected'" :"").">$c_title</option>";
}
```

Finally:

As Chris Baker mentioned stop using **mysql_** and use **mysqli_** or **PDO**.

Comment: Not working still previous results i mean same nothing change. :(

Comment: What is the URL that is loaded after the refresh?

Comment: the change is just in the category id.

Comment: Alex, put the checks on `$_GET` outside the loop, that way you don't have to call `isset` on every iteration. That will generate a notice, depending on error_reporting settings. Use this instead: `$selectedCategory = array_key_exists('cat', $_GET) ? $_GET['cat'] : 0;` and put that above the loop. Then your if statement can be `if ($selectedCategory == $c_id)` -- much cleaner.

Comment: Good changes, Alex :) You can/should start warning about use of `mysql_` too -- it is deprecated, so any new code being created that uses it will be 100% broken some time in the future. I try not to harp about it, but it is important, and code examples that use the old methods without a disclaimer help keep it alive that much longer, which is a bad thing.